# Firebase Realtime Database rules auth !== null not working with Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a project in Firebase that I enable a **Realtime Database** and **Authentication** (with Sign-in with password method).

I was able to sign up, and sign in with Web Api Key just fine. But when I use the `idToken` returned from the Sign-in call, I cannot seems to `read` or `write` despite the fact that I used the rule `".read" : "auth !== null"` and `".write" : "auth !== null"`.

1. Sign up ([Guide Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password)) with the following call:

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]
```

2. Sign in ([Guide Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password)) with the following call:

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]
```

which return a data in the following format:

```
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
  "localId": "kdjRwh9BzSSmPK5GKkn8dSwXok33",
  "email": "<sign-up-email>",
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": "<String-of-token-in-form:::eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InRCME0yQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2lk>",
  "registered": true
```

3. Read data from Realtime Database with:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://<DATABASE-NAME>/users.json?auth=<idToken-gotten-above>'
```

and rules set to

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth!==null"
    }
  }
}
```

The API call returned

```
{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

I was expecting the data correctly returned.

What went wrong?